# icecast and mixxx setup - clients cannot hear my radio station

Tags: javascript, html, icecast

I just finished setting up icecast2 server and mixxx in my computer. I can listen to my radio through the url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/soylatino. However, I asked my friends in another states if they can listen to my radio and they said that they cannot listen anything, but a message of Error #2032 came up after they hit play button. They also have adobe flash player working in their computers. Can someone please tell me if I am doing something wrong by trying to configure my server or maybe something else is wrong?
Thanks a lot in advance for your support.

I am using the following xml parameters in icecast.xml file:

```
<!-- You may have multiple <listener> elements -->
<listen-socket>
<port>8000</port>
<!-- <bind-address>127.0.0.1</bind-address> -->
<!-- <shoutcast-mount>/stream</shoutcast-mount> -->
</listen-socket>
<!--
<relay>
<server>127.0.0.1</server>
<port>8080</port>
<mount>/soylatino</mount>
<local-mount>/different.ogg</local-mount>
<relay-shoutcast-metadata>0</relay-shoutcast-metadata>
</relay>
-->
```

In mixxx live broadcasting settings, I am using the following settings:

Type: icecast2,
Host: 127.0.0.1,
Port: 8000,
Mount: /soylatino,
Login: source,
Password: mypassword,

Then, when I hit OK button, a message appears: 
Mixx has successfully connected to the streaming server.

Next: I wrote the following code in my html page:

```
<div id="container"><a    href="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">Get the Flash Player</a> to see this player.

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.shoutcheap.com/flashplayer/skins/swfobject.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

var s1 = new    SWFObject('http://www.shoutcheap.com/flashplayer/skins/player.swf','player',"340","50","9","#FFFFFF");

s1.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');

s1.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always')        s1.addParam("flashvars","skin=http://www.shoutcheap.com/flashplayer/skins/grungetape.swf&title=Live Stream&type=sound&file=http://127.0.0.1:8000/soylatino%3Ftype%3D.mp3 &13202692901&duration=99999&id=scplayer&autostart=true"); 
s1.write("container");
```

This is my page: www.followperu.com/radio.html

Answer (score 1):

`127.0.0.1` is a special IP address used for loopback.  That is, `127.0.0.1` always means yourself... your own computer.

You can connect to `127.0.0.1` because you're running the server on the same computer as Mixxx.  However, when your friends try to connect to `127.0.0.1`, their browser tries to connect to their own computers, not yours.

While you can use `127.0.0.1`, you need to give your friends your public IP address.  In most home network setups, you only have one public IP address which your router handles.  Your router then assigns private IP addresses to other computers on your network, and handles routing requests between the two networks via NAT.  If you [Google for, "what is my IP address?"](https://www.google.com/search?q=What%20is%20my%20ip%20address), it will give you your public IP address.  (You can also get this information in your router's configuration.)  Next, make sure you have forwarded over port 8000 from your router to your computer's private IP address.  (This private IP address is not the loopback `127.0.0.1`.  It will be in one of the private network blocks, such as `10.0.0.0` or `192.168.0.0` or `172.16.0.0`.)

Comment: Hi Brad, thank you so much for your prompt response. Unfortunately, I didn't have success with my streaming setup. Could you check please what am I doing wrong? This is what I have so far:

1- This is my public IP address: 69.255.5... (A number like this in: iplocation.net) 
2- This is my public IP address: 2601:144:103:700:1c26:1e8... (A number like this in: http://whatismyipaddress.com)
3- IPV4 address: 10.0.0.10 (I think this is the private IP of my computer)
This is what I have so far in icecast.xml:
<hostname>10.0.0.10</hostname>
<port>8000</port>

Comment: I also changed some usernames and passwords (in icecast.xml) to make it work. 

* Mixx server connection:
Type: icecast2
host:10.0.0.10
mount: /soylatino
port: 8000
login:source
password: #######

In my html page I only have the following: 

<audio controls autoplay="autoplay"><source src="http://69.255.......(1st IP address):8000/stream?type=.mp3" type="audio/mp3">Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>

Comment: All the rest keeps the same in icecast.xml. Do you think I should fill or change some tags in icecast.xml? Or maybe there is something wrong with the audio tag in the html page?

Comment: This tags keeps the same:
    <listen-socket>
     <port>8000</port>
     <!-- <bind-address>10.0.0.10</bind-address> --> 
     <!-- <shoutcast-mount>/stream</shoutcast-mount> -->
    </listen-socket>